# Выбрать со строки только правила CSS

Tags: javascript

Есть строка в которой несколько правил CSS.
Пример:

```
".sleep span,body{text-align:center}body{background-color:#EBD8D0;height:100%;margin:0}"
```

Как убрать все селекторы и оставить только правила и их значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте regex:

```
{(.+?)}
```

```js
function getSelectors(source) {
  const template = /{(.+?)}/g;
  let match;
  let output = [];
  while (match = template.exec(source)) {
    output.push(match[1]);
  }

  return output;
}

var results = getSelectors(".sleep span,body{text-align:center}body{background-color:#EBD8D0;height:100%;margin:0}");
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Comment: ты пробовал данное регулярное выражение **в яваскрипте**? По крайней мере в хроме выдает: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<={).+?(?=})/: Invalid group_

Comment: @Grundy мы с вами пива не пили, так что давайте на **вы**. Исправил.

Comment: @IvanKucher обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо пользователю AGS17, за подсказку)

```
const regex = /{[ \n]*(.+?)[ \n]*}/gm;
const str = `html{height:100%}body{display:flex;min-height:100%;font:100 normal 16px/1.6 georgia,times,serif;background:#111}#db{display:none}canvas{display:block;margin:0 auto;align-self:flex-start}.btn{font-size:inherit;width:140px}.info-popup-container{display:inline-block;position:relative}}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Кому нужно вот реализация - https://jsfiddle.net/npzaygn4/2/